# How can I copy all files and folders from one directory to another with similar structure with `find` and `xargs`?

Tags: command-line, find, cp, xargs

For example, I use `find` command `find /usr/share/icons -iname 'foxitreader*'` find the files:

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/FoxitReader.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/FoxitReader.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/FoxitReader.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/FoxitReader.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/FoxitReader.png
```

and I want to use `xargs` copy them to the `.local/share/icons/`, and in the `icons` directory has the same subdirectory structure, which is:

```
 └── hicolor
    ├── 16x16
    │   └── apps
    │       ├── 1B94_WScript.0.png
    │       ├── 1CD8_rundll32.0.png
    │       ├── 1E64_notepad.0.png
    │       ├── 2402_msiexec.0.png
    │       
    ├── 24x24
    │   └── apps
    │       ├── 6C56_Timwp.0.png
    │       └── FoxitReader.png
    ├── 256x256
    │   └── apps
    │       ├── 1E64_notepad.0.png
    │       ├── 2402_msiexec.0.png
    │       ├── 2EF4_wordpad.0.png
    ├── 32x32
    │   └── apps
    │       ├── 1B94_WScript.0.png
    │       ├── 1CD8_rundll32.0.png
    │       ├── 1E64_notepad.0.png
    └── 48x48
        └── apps
            ├── 1CD8_rundll32.0.png
            ├── 1E64_notepad.0.png
            ├── 2402_msiexec.0.png
```

and I just want to copy the files I find, not the whole directory structure, so how can I copy these files to the corresponding directory, like this:
`/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/FoxitReader.png` to the `.local/share/icons/32x32/apps/FoxitReader.png`, etc.
And the `icons` directory already have these subdirectories, and it's not empty, so you can't just use `cp` to merge them, and I use `find` to find the files, and want to use `xargs` to copy them once a time, not more times manually.

Comment: why do not you try to do it manually

Comment: In one command to handle it, it is convenient.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, it is different, I know the basic `cp` commands, and I have used the command for a while, what I want to know is a specific problem to the `cp` command, maybe there is my terrible description confusing you. I want to use `find` and `xargs` command to copy the files once a time, not more times.

Comment: Not exactly, @JacobVlijm, I think I should describe my problem more speicifically.

Comment: Ah, the "*I just want to copy the files I find, not the whole directory structur*" is a new element. How do you find these items? what is the command. The (only) difference with my answer is then that it only should copy listed files, not all. right?

Comment: `find /usr/share/icons -iname 'foxitreader*'` @JacobVlijm

Comment: With a minor python script, would be a piece of cake. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: ok, I think just a command can't do this well, it may need some scripts to do it.

Comment: Sorry very much, I think that I have upvoted your answer is replying to you. I didn't expect that you want the exact reply.

Comment: Yes, it works, but it maybe not a commonly used script, it should be improved, it should match the destination directory according to the source directory, not hardcoded, That's what I want. I think I should improve it. Thanks to your answer, and I am sorry for the reply which is not in time. @JacobVlijm

Comment: Huh? what does this mean?  *"it should be improved"* hardcoded? Sorry, but the answer did *exactly* what you asked for. Again, without communicating, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I mean I can improve it, you give me a good idea, thanks! @JacobVlijm

Comment: It's my mistake not to reply the helpers in time, and I will do well as I can. @JacobVlijm

Comment: Hi @zhenguoli really, trying to help, but it's not working if people post an answer and a vague "It should be improved" and "hardcoded" is the comment (after I ask for it, before you just changed the question again)  *That* is hard to work with, not so much the timing.

Comment: I will try to express clearly, and try to communicate in time, not wasting our time.  @JacobVlijm

Comment: And you are earnest, because I have ask some questions ago, but when I make some comment, some people didn't reply to me, but you are kindhearted, you are waiting for my reply all the time. Thank you very much, and I will reply to helpers in time. @JacobVlijm

Comment: @zhenguoli you' re welcome, sorry if I was unpolite.

Comment: No, you are kindhearted, I should learn to you, it's my blame. @JacobVlijm

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in bash by enabling extended [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html#FTN.AEN17572).

```
shopt -s extglob
```

and then use the `--parents` options of `cp`.

So, go to `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/` and do:

```
cp -R --parent {128x128,32x32}/apps ~/.local/share/icons/
```

Modify the directory names within `{}` to suit your needs.

Eg:

```
ron@ron:~$ tree dir1/          # Destination before copying
dir1/
├── 128x128
│   └── apps
├── 16x16
│   └── apps
├── 32x32
│   └── apps
└── 48x48
    └── apps
karthik@4736Z:~/dir2$ ls hicolor/            # Source structure
128x128  22x22    32     42x42  512x512  72x72  icons             scalable
16x16    24x24    32x32  48     64       8x8    icon-theme.cache  symbolic
192x192  256x256  36x36  48x48  64x64    96x96  index.theme
ron@ron:~/dir2$ tree hicolor/ | head -n 6
hicolor/
├── 128x128
│   ├── actions
│   ├── animations
│   ├── apps
│   │   ├── amazon-store.png
ron@ron:~/dir2/hicolor$ cd hicolor/    
ron@ron:~/dir2/hicolor$ cp -R --parent {128x128,32x32}/apps ../../dir1/
ron@ron:~/dir2/hicolor$ tree ../../dir1/          # Destination after copying
../../dir1/
├── 128x128
│   └── apps
│       ├── amazon-store.png
│       ├── chromium-browser.png
│       ├── credentials-preferences.png
│       ├── deluge.png
│       ├── display-im6.q16.png
│       ├── libreoffice-base.png
│       ├── libreoffice-calc.png
│       ├── libreoffice-draw.png
│       ├── libreoffice-impress.png
│       ├── libreoffice-main.png
│       ├── libreoffice-math.png
│       ├── libreoffice-startcenter.png
│       ├── libreoffice-writer.png
│       ├── ubuntuone-music.png
│       ├── ubuntusoftware.svg
│       ├── vivaldi.png
│       ├── vlc.png
│       └── vlc-xmas.png
├── 16x16
│   └── apps
├── 32x32
│   └── apps
│       ├── aim.png
│       ├── baobab.png
│       ├── bluetooth.png
```

Comment: What I means is that, the `icons` already have the directory structure, please see what I have edited, you may misunderstand my meanings. @Ron

Comment: I use the `find` command, and I want to copy all the files with the same `basename` I find to the corresponding directory, just like `diff -r` do to compare the same subdirectory structure, not just one directory.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your intentions. I've updated my answer. See if it works for you.